# MongoDB - Converting fields from int32 to int64

Tags: php, python, mongodb

I have a vary large dataset in `MongoDB`, in which there are documents with numeric fields. Due to some issue in the data import, some of these fields ended up in `int32 datatype` with some are in `int64 datatype`.

I need to convert all of them to int32. Since many of the fields are nested documents/array I cannot use `MongoChef` or `RoboMongo` to edit the field and do a collection wide replace.

What is my next best option? Would I need to write a script that loop through each document/field and explicitly typecast them to `NumberInt()`. I could do this in `PHP or Python`, but I was wondering if there is a way to do this without writing extra code.

Is there any mongoshell magic that can be done? I would appreciate if any Mongo Masters can give me any insights.

Comment: What is your motivation for changing from int64 to int32? Are you concerned about storage space or are you using another driver (outside of PHP/Python) that has stricter type checking? Also, what specific MongoDB server and driver versions are you using? Some server versions of MongoDB (2.6 through 3.2.10) consider changes in numerical type to be a no-op: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-16801.

Comment: @Stennie: I am in an API environment and MongoDB was earlier storing numbers as int32. The new data that got introduced is in int64 and this causes some concern upstream for the API team, so they have asked it to be int32 for consistency. My MongoDB server is 2.6.12 and the PHP Mongo Driver I believe is 1.6.14.

Comment: Can you post an example of the document structure that needs to be updated and comment on the fields with incorrect types?

Comment: @Stennie: on the road...will update when I get off. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: @Stennie: I was able to use the deprecated MongoInt32 class to achieve what I wanted. I know its not very proper, but i was able to get all Int64 updated to In32 using this class and an older driver which supported it.

Comment: Good to hear you found a solution. I would double-check that the values have definitely been updated to `int32` since the numerical type no-op issue I mentioned (SERVER-16801) affects MongoDB 2.6 server if you are setting individual field values. You should also post an example of your approach here to answer your own question ;-).

Answer (score 0):

To anyone looking to do this and coming here. You can run

```js
db.foo.find().forEach(doc => {
    const newBar = bar.valueOf()
    db.foo.update({
        "_id" : doc._id
    }, {
        "$set" : {
            "bar" : newBar
        }
    })
})
```

in the `mongo` shell. This might not be doable in large collections. The key is to use `.valueOf()` on the `Int64`. You might want to check that this doesn't overflow